# How can I add User Input field in WooCommerce Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add User Input field where users can add text in any product. with or without WordPress REST api.

Comment: Could you expand a bit? Users in the admin panel or customers before adding to cart? Also, should the field be only for the user that added it?

Comment: i want customers to add their text on product page in front.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with code can be a bit tricky as you also need to take into account other areas of WooCommerce, such as the "order again" flow.

If you don't mind using a plugin, you can use the [Advanced Product Fields for WooCommerce plugin](https://www.studiowombat.com/plugin/advanced-product-fields-for-woocommerce/) to add input fields (including text fields) to your product pages. It doesn't use the Woo REST API but integrates well in all areas of WooCommerce.